# Run-time Error 3705 - Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression

Tags: sql, ms-access

could someone please help me make sense of a problem in our access database.  It has suddenly developed an issue linking to mail merged letters; when trying to create a letter from the database form I get the following error: Run-time Error 3705 - Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Log.[Unique Ref] = '.

I've found the code I think it refers to but have no idea what I'm looking for to fix the issue:

```
SQLStr = "SELECT Addressees.*, Log.*, SPRN.* " & _
    "FROM SPRN RIGHT JOIN (Addressees RIGHT JOIN Log ON " & _
    "Addressees.Name = Log.[To Name]) ON SPRN.Post = Log.Responsible " & _
    "WHERE Log.[Unique Ref] = " & [Unique Ref].Value

SQLStr2 = "SELECT Files.*, Log.* " & _
"FROM Files RIGHT JOIN Log ON Files.[File Reference ID] = Log.[File Ref]" & _
    "WHERE Log.[Unique Ref] = " & [Unique Ref].Value


'Get the current database
Set dbsCurrent = CurrentDb
'Get the query that will be used by Word for the mail merge
Set qryTest = dbsCurrent.QueryDefs("ForLetter")
Set qryTest2 = dbsCurrent.QueryDefs("ForFolder")


'Change the SQL statement for that query, so it returns all
' related fields for only this entry
qryTest.SQL = SQLStr
qryTest2.SQL = SQLStr2
```

The `qryTest.SQL = SQLStr` is highlighted on the system so not sure if this is alluding to the issue.  The database was set up some time ago and MS Access on our system has recently been upgraded from 2003 to 2007; however all was working fine until last week.  We can still use the database; it's just the link to the letters that seems to be broken.

Comment: Where is `[Unique Ref].Value` defined?

Comment: Copy the sql generated by the vbcode to notepad or somewhere you can read it easily. Look at what comes afer 'Log.[Unique Ref] =.  If it's nothing, figure out why.

Comment: It could be that the `Log()` function was not introduced until Access 2007, so it's now a protected keyword in SQL, where before it wasn't. Perhaps change instances of `Log.` to `[Log].` and see if that clears it up.

Comment: Agree with @DanBracuk... the best way to identify your faulty query is to debug your program and get the output of your String variables (through ? variablename in your console assuming your using VBA). Then you should be able to manually run that text output against a new query to identify which one is failing and why.